# Django/Postgres: in a query with a conditional annotation, return an ArrayField with a certain value in it?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using Python 2.7, Postgres 9.6 and Django 1.11. I have a model, `Person`, with two `CharField`s on it, `director_id` and `company_id`. I'd like to annotate it according to a certain condition: when `director_id` is not null, do a subquery performing an `ArrayAgg` that gives me back an array of the `company_id`s associated with it (fine, got that working); when it is not I'd like to return an array of length 1 simply containing the `company_id` for this `Person`. Is there a way to specify that I want `default` to give back an array with a certain value in it?

```
Person.objects.annotate(
    aggregated_company_ids=Case(
        When(director_id__isnull=False, then=Subquery(aggregated_company_ids)),
        default=[F("company_id")],  # ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'F'
        output_field=ArrayField(models.CharField()),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I can't really test this easily, but default isn't as powerfull as When, maybe using an other When instead of default would work ?
`When(director_id__isnull=True, ...` for example.
It's not pretty but should do it.

Comment: @Oniro Thanks for the suggestion, I get the same ProgrammingError though. I think the problem might be that it doesn't recognize `[F("company_id")]` as specifying what I want to specify, namely an array with a particular field's value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `ArrayAgg(F("company_id"))` worked and gave me an array of with just the one `company_id` in it:

```
Person.objects.annotate(
    aggregated_company_ids=Case(
        When(director_id__isnull=False, then=Subquery(aggregated_company_ids)),
        default=ArrayAgg(F("company_id")),
        output_field=ArrayField(models.CharField()),
    ),
)
```

Not sure whether this is the only and best solution but it's the only one I've found.